# How to sum input numbers using while loop? (python)

Tags: python

Beginner question, I have to create a program that asks user to input numbers (input 0 to break), then calculates the amount of numbers in total and then the sum of the input numbers.
How do i print the sum of user-input numbers using while loop? This is what I got so far

```
amount = 0
while True:
    amount += 1
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    
print(f"Numbers in total: {amount-1}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Same as you have `amount = 0`, create a variable `total = 0`. And, inside the loop, add `total += number`, after the line where you are reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the same technique that you used for the number of inputs:

```
amount = 0
number = 0
while True:
    amount += 1
    number += int(input("Number: "))
    if number == 0:
        break

print(f"Numbers in total: {amount-1}")
print(f"Sum of the numbers : {number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_numbers=0
total_sum=0
while True:
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    number_of_numbers += 1
    total_sum += number

print("Total number of numbers is: ", number_of_numbers)
print("Total sum is: ", total_sum)
```

You were almost there, just had to add another variable for obtaining the total sum. Apart from that, it's almost the same as your code. Just that added the if condition before adding the total number.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
iteration = 0
amount = 0
while True:
    iteration++
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    amount += number
    print(f"Sum so far: {amount}")
    
print(f"Numbers in total: {iteration-1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sometimes you can use a try...except. An example is below, though does more than just that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

number = "Enter an integer, "
number += "the input ends if a zero is entered: "
msg = "No numbers were entered except zero"

sumNum = 0
count_positives = 0
count_negatives = 0

flag = 1

try:
    while flag:
    
        prompt = int(input(number))
        
        if (prompt < 0):
            count_negatives += 1
            
        if (prompt > 0):
            count_positives += 1

        sumNum += prompt
        totalNums = count_positives + count_negatives
        avg = sumNum / totalNums

        if (prompt == 0):
            print(f"The number of positives is {count_positives}")
            print(f"The number of negatives is {count_negatives}")
            print(f"The total is {sumNum}")
            print(f"The average is {avg}")
            break

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(msg)
```